# Max date when grouping - max date is same for all

Tags: mysql

Why is it that I can do this and get expected results:

```
select UserID, max(ClickInDate) as LatestClickInDate
from EventClickIns
group by UserID
order by UserID
```

Results:

```
UserID LatestClickInDate
49     2017-10-13 08:12:58
65     2017-10-10 06:27:53
67     2017-10-11 06:40:12
89     2017-10-13 08:07:59
```

...but when I do this:

```
select u.ID, max(eci.ClickInDate) AS LatestClickInDate
from Users_WebEvents ue
join Users u
on ue.UserID = u.ID
left join Invitations i
on ue.EventID = i.WebEventID
left join EventClickIns eci
on i.InvitationID = eci.InvitationID
where ue.EventID = 1
group by u.ID
```

I get the same `LatestClickInDate` for every record, which is the MAX date across all rows in `EventClickIns`.

```
UserID LatestClickInDate
49     2017-10-13 11:06:00
50     2017-10-13 11:06:00
52     2017-10-13 11:06:00
89     2017-10-13 11:06:00
```

**== UPDATE w/ADD'L DATA ==**

```
select ID, EventName from WebEvents
```

Currently only 1 record:

```
ID  EventName
1   Ultimate - {DAY} Noon
```

A few `Invitations` records:

```
select * from Invitations

InvitationID WebEventID InviteDate
3            1          2017-10-12 02:00:04
4            1          2017-10-12 07:00:02
5            1          2017-10-13 07:00:01
```

A few `Users_WebEvents` records:

```
select ID, UserID, EventID, LastEmailDate from Users_WebEvents

ID  UserID  EventID  LastEmailDate
50  493     1        2017-10-13 07:00:45
51  707     1        2017-10-13 07:00:46
52  516     1        2017-10-13 07:00:48
53  162     1        2017-10-13 07:00:49
```

A few `EventClickIns` records:

```
select * from EventClickIns

ID  InvitationID  UserID  ClickInDate
14  5             703     2017-10-13 08:35:30
15  5             123     2017-10-13 08:38:09
16  5             383     2017-10-13 09:30:47
17  5             725     2017-10-13 10:13:09
```

*IMPORTANT: In all cases, WebEventID is the same as EventID.* It's an unfortunate inconsistency.

What I am expecting is the **MAX date per user per event**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check on `where ue.EventID = 1`. It seems to be restricting the output.

Comment: You need to add some sample data to reproduce this issue

Comment: There's only one event, number 1, so maybe there's only one date involved, the max data. But you haven't given enough info. We don't even know whether there can be more than one date per event or dates per person or dates per person per event, etc etc over those tables. You need to read & act on [mcve]. (Part of which will be, add joins one by one to find minimal code exhibiting the problem.)

Comment: *"MAX date per user per event"* -- `MAX()` goes to the `SELECT` clause (it already is there) and "per user per event" go to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I apologize for not posting enough data sets. I have fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, this info makes it so much easier to provide an answer, but it's late for me, so could only make a quick attempt. **oops, more neeeded** darn missed table EventClickIns

Comment: amended answer below, with working sqlfiddle derived from the added info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I amended the UserID in EventClickIns to enable a result:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f6b5b/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE WebEvents
    (`ID` int, `EventName` varchar(21))
;

INSERT INTO WebEvents
    (`ID`, `EventName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Ultimate - {DAY} Noon')
;


CREATE TABLE Invitations
    (`InvitationID` int, `WebEventID` int, `InviteDate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Invitations
    (`InvitationID`, `WebEventID`, `InviteDate`)
VALUES
    (3, 1, '2017-10-12 02:00:04'),
    (4, 1, '2017-10-12 07:00:02'),
    (5, 1, '2017-10-13 07:00:01')
;


CREATE TABLE Users_WebEvents
    (`ID` int, `UserID` int, `EventID` int, `LastEmailDate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Users_WebEvents
    (`ID`, `UserID`, `EventID`, `LastEmailDate`)
VALUES
    (50, 493, 1, '2017-10-13 07:00:45'),
    (51, 707, 1, '2017-10-13 07:00:46'),
    (52, 516, 1, '2017-10-13 07:00:48'),
    (53, 162, 1, '2017-10-13 07:00:49')
;


CREATE TABLE EventClickIns
    (`ID` int, `InvitationID` int, `UserID` int, `ClickInDate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO EventClickIns
    (`ID`, `InvitationID`, `UserID`, `ClickInDate`)
VALUES
    (14, 5, 162, '2017-10-13 08:35:30'),
    (15, 5, 493, '2017-10-13 08:38:09'),
    (16, 5, 516, '2017-10-13 09:30:47'),
    (17, 5, 707, '2017-10-13 10:13:09')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
      e.*
    , uc.*
from WebEvents e
inner join (
    select w.UserID, w.EventID, max(c.ClickInDate)
    from Users_WebEvents w
    inner join EventClickIns c on w.UserID  = c.UserID  
    inner join Invitations i on c.InvitationID = i.InvitationID and w.EventID = i.WebEventID 
    group by w.UserID, w.EventID
    ) uc on e.ID = uc.EventID
WHERE e.ID = 1
ORDER BY e.EventName, uc.UserID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f6b5b/5/0)**:

```
| ID |             EventName | UserID | EventID |   max(c.ClickInDate) |
|----|-----------------------|--------|---------|----------------------|
|  1 | Ultimate - {DAY} Noon |    162 |       1 | 2017-10-13T08:35:30Z |
|  1 | Ultimate - {DAY} Noon |    493 |       1 | 2017-10-13T08:38:09Z |
|  1 | Ultimate - {DAY} Noon |    516 |       1 | 2017-10-13T09:30:47Z |
|  1 | Ultimate - {DAY} Noon |    707 |       1 | 2017-10-13T10:13:09Z |
```

Comment: But it wouldn't make sense to be an outer join

Comment: @Strawbery perhaps not; but that is the least of the issues with it I'm not suggesting  it is a full solution

Comment: I apologize for not posting enough data sets. I have fixed that.